# Vapor server and companion iOS app examples

Tags: vapor

One of the reasons advocates of swift server side give for the use of swift is that it allows iOS developers to develop backends for their apps. But, I do not see many example of this usage pattern.

There is a [chat-ios](https://github.com/vapor-community/chat-ios-example) example but that is using websockets.

Are there any server and companion iOS app examples available?

One of the difficulties of using a custom server is handling the possible poor comms in iOS app usage. I would like to see if any project out there have handled this well.

One of the reasons for using parse/firebase is the builtin client side support for syncing/retry. Are there any resources/frameworks for client side apps that can be used to give this reliability for custom backends.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Swift Packages for both iOS/macOS clients and Vapor backend development for some time.  I'm in the process of gathering the lessons learned into a generic set of Open Source repositories: `VaporExampleLabs/Synergy*`.

It is possible to have Swift Packages which can be used on the Swift server side, and on iOS devices and in macOS applications.  A greater separation between the views (Vapor `View`, iOS `UIView`, macOS `NSView`) and underlaying application logic, allows more code to be shared in Swift Packages across the platforms.

The `VaporExampleLabs/Synergy*` collection of packages & projects provides various working pieces of how to setup a Vapor server, iOS device client and a macOS client to use the same Swift Packages.

Each part highlights some key findings for the use of a Swift code shared in both Server backend and Client device software development.

Main Obervations:

- Separate as much application logic from the views as possible for placement into Swift Packages.
- Consider using Swift and/or C libraries which are across platform.
- Xcode sometimes requires extra manual steps like adding the C header files in the build phase.
- Swift Packages can be generated as Xcode projects for use as subprojects in the iOS and macOS applications. The Swift Package subprojects serve as a workaround until iOS/macOS/tvOS applications can build with SPM.

*Note: The Synergy set of projects and packages are still a **work in progress** for gathering lessons learned. The goal is to create a full (self-contained) set of backend-to-client connected examples sharing common Swift Packages.*

---

**SynergySqliteC**

Sometimes lower level libraries are not common between the server and device.  For example, the database Object Relationship Model (ORM) is different for Vapor and iOS/macOS have CoreData. Vapor provides Fluent. iOS/macOS provides CoreData.

This example illustrates direct use the SQLite C source code at the lowest level.

`SynergySqliteC ⇗` shows how to setup a cross platform C library into a Swift Package.

A pure C package may require manual addition of the *.h files to the project treee for building in an Xcode project.

**SynergySQLiteFramework**

`SynergySQLiteFramework ⇗` provides a *generic* Swift framework for using the C-base Swift Package `SynergySqliteC`.

**SynergyAPI**

`SynergyAPI ⇗` provides the Codable interface for the collection of Synergy applications.  Uses the generics SQLite package `SynergySQLiteFramework`.

**SynergyVapor**

`SynergyVapor ⇗` provides an example Vapor web application which uses the `SynergyAPI`.

**Synergy Clients**

`Synergy ⇗` provides both an iOS and macOS client Xcode projects.  Both the iOS and macOS clients use the `SynergyAPI` package.

**Swift Packages in iOS/macOS Applications**

Swift Package Manager Project stated the following prior to 2019.06.03:

> Note that at this time the Package Manager has no support for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms.

On 2019.06.03, the [Swift Package Manager Project](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager) was updated to indicate some SPM support is present in Xcode 11.

> Xcode 11 integrates with libSwiftPM to provide support for iOS, watchOS, and tvOS platforms.

Even though the Swift Package manager *can not directly* create an iOS or macOS application, Swift Packages can still be used as subprojects in the respective Xcode application projects.

```bash
cd SynergyAPI

swift package generate-xcodeproj \
    --xcconfig-overrides Package.iOS.xcconfig \
    --output SynergyAPI_iOS

swift package generate-xcodeproj \
    --xcconfig-overrides Package.macOS.xcconfig \
    --output SynergyAPI_macOS
```

[image: SubprojectSynergyAPI]

### Resources

- [StackOverflow: How do I use Swift Package Manager with an existing macOS project? ⇗](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837369/how-do-i-use-swift-package-manager-with-an-existing-macos-project)
- [StackOverflow: Vapor server and companion iOS app examples ⇗](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717355/vapor-server-and-companion-ios-app-examples/48373393#comment97266087_48373393)
- Tutorial: ["Sharing Swift Code Between iOS and Server Applications" ⇗](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2401813-sharing-swift-code-between-ios-and-server-applications)

Answer (score 2):

This [official list of Vapor projects](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/master/Documents/PROJECTS.md) contains a couple of iOS/server project pairs.

This is probably the best example from that list.

Server: https://github.com/cocoaheadsru/server

Client: https://github.com/cocoaheadsru/application

Comment: The "official list of Vapor projects" _PROJECTS.md_ was [removed on Feb 20, 2018
from GitHub](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/commit/584c2ab59962728cb2ff0287a799c226096d2297#diff-e4092990b7c30d2c29fab6d117b064a8). The last update to the [PROJECTS.md appears to have been Sep 9, 2017](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/1e59b819fabfa912e3dd7f7739c35f4a865a2fa2/Documents/PROJECTS.md).