# Use UIKit with Vapor or Kitura

Tags: swift, server-side, vapor, kitura

I have developed an iOS App and would like to create a web API with some parts of my code. This API will send an UIImage generated from a UIView.
The problem I have with Vapor is that I only managed to use AppKit, not UIKit. Certainly because the Xcode project with Vapor is a MacOS project.
Is there a way to use UIKit or iOS Swift code with Vapor or any other solutions like Kitura ???

Thanks for your help :)

Regards,

Comment: "create a web API with some parts of my code" ... it is possible for some Swift code reuse across the iOS/Linux/macOS/ platforms. The key is to _separate platform specific elements_ (e.g. UIView, NSView, Vapor View) from reuseable Swift code which is build on the cross platform Swift Foundation. The reuseable cross platform Swift code can then be used in a Swift Package on all platforms. See [Vapor server and companion iOS app examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717355/vapor-server-and-companion-ios-app-examples/55368410#55368410)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your Backend API Server (Vapor or Kitura) to run in a hosted environment, it will need to be able to run on Linux - where only Foundation is supported.

You can still transfer `UIImages` between iOS app and server, but you'll need to convert the `UIImage` to Data first (using something like `UIImage.jpegData()`)

You can see an example of this in the "FoodTrackerBackend" tutorial for Kitura here:
    https://github.com/IBM/FoodTrackerBackend

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will do this :)