# Using Swift Vapor instead of PHP

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I need an advise from an experienced Swift developer who have used Vapor framework.

I was planning to use php to create a control panel for an iOS and Android apps, but I was told to use Vapor `http://vapor.codes/` instead of it.

Can anyone answer this question I have about Vapor? Searching internet didn't give me much answers and created some confusion.

- When Vapor is ready, will we have a front end for it? I mean a user interface. Like I would have if the backend was created using php, and it's frontend using Bootstrap?

Comment: you can have a look at good tutorial on Raywenderlich's website [Templating Vapor Applications with Leaf](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1002448-templating-vapor-applications-with-leaf)

Comment: As FYI: Here is a example set of bootstrap front end template webpages which use Vapor as the backend <https://github.com/VaporExamplesLab/quickstart-bootstrap-sampler> ... also vapor is compatible with a range of front end stacks ... for example,  [`vapor.codes` uses Vapor with Vue.js](https://github.com/vapor/website). ... and a Swift Package can be structured for [both iOS and Vapor reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717355/vapor-server-and-companion-ios-app-examples/55368410#55368410)

Comment: It seems that a question rephrasing to something like "Can Vapor provide (or work with) a front end UI similar to what PHP can do with Bootstrap? If yes, how?" ... might re-focus the question to be more "on-topic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vapor you could render html pages using [Leaf](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/leaf/getting-started/)

So yeah, you could build some website and/or admin panel using Vapor.